# Iterating over array in i18next

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next

There is a way I can iterate and render each item of an array of string/objects?

```
i18n
    .use(languageDetector)
    .use(reactI18nextModule)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        resources: {
            en: {
                home: {
                    data:[
                        {id:1,val:"Item1"},
                        {id:2,val:"Item2"},
                        {id:3,val:"Item3"},
                        {id:4,val:"Item4"}]
                },
            }
        }
});
```

in component:

```
<FlatList
        data={t('home:data')} //--cannot do this
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item>{item.val}</Item>}
/>
```

Comment: Are you using `react-native-i18n` package?

Comment: nop, my dependencies are `'i18next` and `react-i18next`. My app is inside Expo, I'm not sure I can use `react-native-i18n`. I would also avoid to remap the array in my component, the array is pretty big ~500 items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way

```
<FlatList
    data={t('home:data', { returnObjects: true })}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    renderItem={ ({item}) => <Text> {item.val}</Text>}
/>
```

FlatList wraps each element in an `item` object 
 (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html).

Comment: using returnObjects is correct. And not i18next is wrapping into item but react-native flat list see the sample https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html -> renderItem={ ({ item }) => <Text> {item.val}</Text>}